# How to create a slide effect with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <div data-ng-click="showContent()" data-ng-show="!visible" class="fly-in-group">{{heading}}</div>

    <div data-ng-show="visible" class="fly-in-group">
        <div data-ng-click="showHeadings()">Terug naar jaaroverzicht</div>
        <div data-ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.fly-in-group{
   -webkit-transition:all 2s linear 0s;
    transition:all 2s linear 0s;

    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    line-height:15px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
}

.fly-in-group.ng-hide-add, 
.fly-in-group.ng-hide-remove{

    display: block !important;
}

.fly-in-group.ng-hide-add{
    position: relative;
    right: -9999px;
}

.fly-in-group.ng-hide-remove{
    position: relative;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/8UPva/3/)

What I try to accomplish is that when 'Some caption' is clicked, this div 'slides out' to the left and that the other div (with the items) 'slides in' from the right.

I want to accomplish this using Angular + CSS3, but I just can't figure it out. Could someone help me and explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions depend on specific attributes changing.

When an element is hidden with ngHide, the class 'ng-hide' is added to the element. Thus, if we want things to slide in and out, we need to overwrite .ng-hide so it changes the attribute we're interested in. The critical point is that we also have to override .ng-hide's default `display: none`, which otherwise destroys the transition.

Tweaking the in-between classes, .ng-hide-add and .ng-hide-remove, is not necessary in this case.

To solve the question with the minimally required changes, change the CSS to this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8UPva/4/)):

```
.fly-in-group{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear 0s;
    transition:all 0.5s linear 0s;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    line-height:15px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
}

.fly-in-group.ng-hide {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999px;
}
```

My one caveat is that I changed .fly-in-group's position to absolute. I did this to prevent an annoying flicker during transition.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use css3 transforms and not use "left". I've also updated the angular version.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fernandopasik/GcUjL/

```
.fly-in-group {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s linear 0s;
    transition:all 0.2s linear 0s;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height:15px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.fly-in-group.ng-hide {
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```